# XAMPP Apache Won't Start after PHP Upgrade

Tags: php, macos, apache, xampp

Apache won't start on Mac with XAMPP. I tried updating PHP from `5.5.6` to PHP `5.6.8`, and since that update XAMPP wouldn't start Apache. I tried completely re-installing XAMPP, but same issue.

Help would be appreciated, I'm more than happy to post any information that is necessary, not sure where to start. I've done a lot of looking around and haven't been able to find anything that points me in the right direction - I checked the `Apache error_logs` and there aren't any.

Comment: Have you got any error related to port 80 ? If yes, Can you share that here please.

Comment: No, that was one of the first things I checked. I've also tried switching it to 8080 just in case. But in Activity Monitor, port 80 is clean.

Comment: Whats the Apache Web Server "Status" in XAMPP, Once you start the service, Is it "Starting" ?

Comment: Status starts at Stopped (obviously), I click Start and then it switches to "Starting...", and then it goes back to Stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

**Solution#1**

This solution worked perfectly fine for me..

1) Close XAMPP control

2) Open Activity Monitor(Launchpad->Other->Activity Monitor)

3) Select filter for All processes (default is My processes)

4) In fulltext search type: httpd

5) Kill all httpd items

6) Relaunch XAMPP control and launch apache again

**OR, Solution#2**

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

This command kills Apache server that was pre-installed on MAC OS X.

**OR, Solution#3**

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

This will disable OSX's built-in Apache server and allows XAMPP to start on 80.

**Now once Apache starts successfully modify the .htaccess file**

Apache needs to be configured to recognize index.php as an index file. While adding 'DirectoryIndex index.php' to a .htaccess file may work,

**NOTE:**

In general, you should never use .htaccess files
This is quoted from http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/htaccess.html
Although this refers to an older version of apache, I believe the principle still applies.

Adding the following to your `httpd.conf` (if you have access to it) is considered better form, causes less server overhead and has the exact same effect:

```
<Directory /myapp>
DirectoryIndex index.php
</Directory>
```

Comment: I'd tried the first solution a couple of times already this morning. Killing Mac's apache did work. But unfortunately, only partially. Now XAMPP can start the packaged Apache, but none of the scripts work within XAMPP, even their index.php, which indicates a deeper issue. Also, I assume when my computer restarts apachectl will be on again and I'll have to close it? Looking for a permanent solution here.

Comment: Checking the error_log for Apache now that it actually started, some errors cropped up:

[Sun May 03 12:49:13.006861 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 1501] AH01906: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Sun May 03 12:49:13.007099 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 1501] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun May 03 12:49:13.007642 2015] [suexec:notice] [pid 1501] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/suexec)

Comment: [Sun May 03 12:49:14.002043 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 1502] AH01906: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Sun May 03 12:49:14.002182 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 1502] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun May 03 12:49:14.002401 2015] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 1502] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sun May 03 12:49:14.002428 2015] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 1502] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...

Comment: [Sun May 03 12:49:14.055730 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1502] AH00163: Apache/2.4.12 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1m PHP/5.6.8 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun May 03 12:49:14.055781 2015] [core:notice] [pid 1502] AH00094: Command line: '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/httpd -E /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/logs/error_log -D SSL -D PHP'

Comment: Solution #3 wouldn't work. It says: /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: Could not find specified service

Comment: Search for "org.apache.httpd.plist" inside /System/Library/ and modify the path according to your system. Sometimes rebooting OSX prevents XAMPP from starting on 80 even though Web Sharing says it's off. Solution is to toggle Web Sharing on then off again, then XAMPP will start.

Comment: Do one thing, run below command first
`sudo apachectl start`
then run Solution#3

Comment: Running the commands for Solution #3 in that order worked, but I wasn't able to locate the httpd plist in /System/Library.

Comment: No Problem, What I am expecting you to do is to run `sudo apachectl start ` then `sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
`. Are you able to execute them ?

Comment: Those are the commands I used, it didn't add the plist to /System/Library

Comment: That's not an issue. Did they execute successfully ?

Comment: Yes, they did: "Running the commands for Solution #3 in that order worked,"

Comment: Ok. Can you now try starting Apache Web Server on XAMPP ?

Comment: Restarted Apache from XAMPP Control Panel. It starts just fine, but the scripts still don't work.

Comment: Ok. So now you have the Apache running on your system. Now to get the scripts working on your system modify .htaccess file. I have updated the answer for you.

Comment: That's not the issue though...going to a file directly it doesn't load. PHP or HTML, or even a directory tree. Doesn't sound like Apache is functioning correctly to me.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated PHP to 8.0 in xampp by renaming old PHP folder to PHP_7.4
and new pasted new php8 folder as php folder, it gave me same error,

**SOLUTION**

Step1: backup old php folder,

Step2: Paste php8 files in to old PHP folder and overwrite existing files,

Done: Restart Apache it should start